# Etherscan API get transaction status from getLogs api call

Tags: transactions, erc-20, events

I am using the Etherscan API to get a list of ERC20 transfer events for a contract, that are relevant to my address:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs

`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=1652080864&toBlock=latest&address=0xa4bbe66f151b22b167127c770016b15ff97dd35c&topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef&topic2=0x0000000000000000000000004103c267fba03a1df4fe84bc28092d629fa3f422&apikey=<APIKEY>`

The response from my API call is as follows:

```
{
        "address": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
        "topics": ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", "0x000000000000000000000000dc7a1ad13b9c03da793b512766c39cc990a6e3b0", "0x0000000000000000000000004103c267fba03a1df4fe84bc28092d629fa3f422"],
        "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008473b70",
        "blockNumber": "0xe0f2a5",
        "timeStamp": "0x6278fc7b",
        "gasPrice": "0xbdc814c53",
        "gasUsed": "0xb41d",
        "logIndex": "0x85",
        "transactionHash": "0x746fa361320fe7365e7001693ee05db243a5d14086c85a105db1e65eed3d7d7e",
        "transactionIndex": "0x2f"
    }
```

Is it possible to derive the [transaction status](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction_receipt) from this data? I am trying to avoid calling an additional API call as I will be cycling through a lot of transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverted transactions don't have logs, so any transaction that has logs, must be a transaction that got mined and didn't revert.

So `status` must be `true` for any transaction you receive from getLogs.

[Error handling: Assert, Require, Revert and Exceptions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)

When a transaction fails it reverts its state -

> Such an exception undoes all changes made to the state in the current call (and all its sub-calls) and flags an error to the caller.

Since state is reverted, nothing changes including events.

Comment: thanks, so a transaction like this won't have logs? https://etherscan.io/tx/0x608835629e3260ed94191409d4fd1e17b9d7d34ebd9b4d65ce041cdecfcf42a8

Comment: Exactly, failed tx = no logs.

Comment: thank you, do you have any docs you can point me to to learn more about that?

Comment: Added explanations to answer.